# Load multiple JSON files in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to teach myself Flutter and i am creating some imaginary situations, lets say that i have a JSON file with some members of a company where it has information as below. For instance John is from Berlin and I want to load another JSON file with weather from Berlin.

```
[
 {
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "age": 25,
  "description": "lorem ipsum dolorum",
  "city": "Berlin"
 }
]
```

This is the file with the Berlin weather.

```
[
 {
  "city" : "Berlin",
  "weather" :
    {
      "monday": 23,
      "tuesday": 24 
      ...
    }
 }
]
```

Here is the code with a future builder that loads my asset, as I understand this allows me to load only one json file, which in most cases should be fine, but my imaginary situation requires to load another file.

```dart
body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(
                'assets/file.json'),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              ...
```

Any help on how to achieve this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap both calls in an asynchronous method and then await on that:

```
Future<Map<String, String>> loadJson() async {
  final jsonA = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/fileA');
  final jsonB = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/fileB');
  return { 
    'fileA': jsonA, 
    'fileB': jsonB,
  };
}

...

FutureBuilder(
  future: loadJson(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    var fileA = snapshot.data['fileA'];
    var fileB = snapshot.data['fileB'];
    ...
```

You can return it as a list or in a custom class or whatever, this is just to show the idea.